# Why is MAC encrypted in TLS data transmission?

Tags: tls, mac

Referring the slide 16 from this [link](https://www.cse.iitm.ac.in/%7Echester/courses/19e_ns/slides/8_TLS.pdf):

[image]

I want to ask why is MAC encrypted along with the data to be transmitted. Why isn't MAC just appended at the end of encrypted data ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does TLS do Authenticate-then-Encrypt instead of Encrypt-then-Authenticate?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25885/why-does-tls-do-authenticate-then-encrypt-instead-of-encrypt-then-authenticate)

Comment: If you mean encrypt-**and**-MAC (MAC over plaintext) then have a look here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/205/1172. You might leak information about the plaintext if the sequence number is not unique or present. Feel free to clarify & update your question if you think your question has not been answered.